# osmosdr source on rpi2: No module named _osmosdr_swig

Tags: python, gnuradio

I'm trying to use osmosdr source in gnuradio on a raspberryPi2. 
With osmosdr from git i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urmet.py", line 20, in <module>
    import osmosdr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osmosdr/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from osmosdr_swig import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osmosdr/osmosdr_swig.py", line 17, in <module>
    _osmosdr_swig = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osmosdr/osmosdr_swig.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_osmosdr_swig')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _osmosdr_swig
```

And with osmosdr from apt-get:

```
linux; GNU C++ version 6.2.0 20161010; Boost_106100; UHD_003.009.005-0-unknown

gr-osmosdr 0.1.4 (0.1.4) gnuradio 3.7.10
built-in source types: file osmosdr fcd rtl rtl_tcp uhd miri hackrf bladerf rfspace airspy soapy redpitaya 
*** Error in `python': corrupted double-linked list: 0x01259bf0 ***
Annullato
```

And with pybombs I can't install:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 641: invalid continuation byte
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got the double linked list error as well with rasbian stretch 9.3 on a rpi3:

```
*** Error in `python': corrupted double-linked list: ... ***
```

Additionally sometimes gnuradio crashed with a segfault as well after initializing the osmosdr block.

It now works after installing gnuradio and libhackrf from the deb repo and compiling the gnuradio block gr-osmosdr from the source.